# Rtorrent under cygwin: watch folder does not handle wildcard

Tags: cygwin, rtorrent

So I'm running rtorrent on cygwin (windows 7 pc). I just installed basic cygwin and the rtorrent 0.9.4 package (including dependencies the installer prompted).

I made a downloads, watch and session folder and tested with a basic config file by manually selecting a torrent with the cli: it downloaded perfectly :)

Then I just added the 'schedule' command easily found on most google examples, but rtorrent would not load any torrent in my watch folder.

After some testing I found schedule DID load and start the torrent if I explicitly type the **full** path name of the torrent, e.g. /home/user/watch/simple.torrent. As this defeats the purpose of having a watch folder my question is how do I get the wildcard method to work?

Notes:

- The specific line in my config file: `schedule = startdl,0,30,load_start=/home/myuser/torrents/*.torrent`
- My .rtorrent.rc file (with watchfolder) works on an ubuntu system.
- I tried renaming the torrent to exclude special characters: e.g. simple.torrent.
- I tried one and two torrents in the watch folder.
- I tried giving the torrent full permissions.
- I checked for typos in the config file.

Guesses:

- Missing an app
- A physical limitation of windows
- I got the wrong version of rtorrent